# IIS 7 and ASP.NET 4 timeout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have 3 applications on the same web server. Two of them are configured in separate ASP.NET 4 application pools and and one of them is on an ASP.NET 2 application pool.

I'm experiencing intermitent timeouts when accessing those apps during the day. To track down this timeouts, I have setup a ping monitoring service (motive.com). Here is a sample of the timeout ocurrencies log:

```
app     date                            downtime        main reason
APP2    19-September-2012, at 14:51 4 mins 50 secs  connect() timed out!
APP1    19-September-2012, at 14:51 4 mins 50 secs  connect() timed out!
APP2    19-September-2012, at 14:11 2 mins 50 secs  couldn't connect to host
APP1    19-September-2012, at 14:11 2 mins 50 secs  couldn't connect to host
APP2    19-September-2012, at 9:17  2 mins 41 secs  couldn't connect to host
APP1    19-September-2012, at 9:17  2 mins 41 secs  couldn't connect to host
...
```

As you can see, both ASP.net 4 pools are timing out simultaneously. I'm also monitoring the ASP.NET 2.0 app pool web site and I haven't have one single timeout!

There's no pattern whatsoever related to the time of the day that it occurs (both day/night). Intervals between timeouts don't follow a pattern either, sometimes they happen after 40 minutes, others take some hours in between.

The timeout never lasts more than 5 minutes, but they also vary from 2 to 5 minutes randomly.

At first I thought it might have something to do with application pool recycling but I've checked and recycling is set to occur after 24 hours and disabled for other events (memory peaks, etc.).

The site is infrequently accessed (it's in beta test), so there are no huge number of access, workers demand, memory consumption, etc.

I've also checked the IIS log and there are 2 to 5 minutes gaps during the hours of downtime reported by the monitoring service, but no error message. I also checked the Windows event log and haven't found anything unusual in system and application events.

I'm really desperate right now. If someone could help me out, I'd be really thankful.

Best Regards,
Eduardo de Freitas

Comment: "it's in beta test" - Any chance this is an application level issue? Are you programmatically logging application level events (e.g. total time to satisfy request for X)?

Comment: One of the asp.net web sites is a web app and the other is basically a static mvc web page. And they both are simultaneously inaccessible. There are no logged users or visitors requesting these pages (besides the monitoring service).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say, but one thing to check is in the web.config if you have   This should be set to false, see this link for more details and additional items to look for: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MostCommonASPNETSupportIssuesReportingFromDeepInsideMicrosoftDeveloperSupport.aspx

Comment: Well, as I am beta testing, they were in debug mode. Changed both web.configs to release and the problem persists :(